# Keep format of a table in bash when reaches end of terminal

Tags: linux, bash, truncate

As of now I'm trying to make something like truncate lines in bash, but, and this is the part that for some reason I keep being unable to do, I need to keep the format of them.
I have 3 lines of output:

- Titles of a table
- First line of values
- Second line of values

When it reaches the end of the terminal, it loses format because jumps to the next line, when I need to print them always keeping the format.

My code is:

```
columns=$(tput cols)
(3 fors with printfs in them) | fmt -w$columns
```

Which saves correctly the width of the terminal, but doesn't truncate it well.

Comment: Hi , Welcome to SO.  Please share [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with simply calculating dynamically the width of the console, and dividing it by the size of the bar that I needed to print, so when that value, you can just make a loop with that info.